# When retrieving data from sql, i want to use the where condition as a variable

Tags: javascript, sql, database

I am writing code in conjunction with sql on node js.

I want to load the data according to the condition, and I want to dynamically get the condition depending on the variable.

Here is the current code:

```
db.all ("select CollectionID, CollectionName from Collection where 
CollectionID = abc", function () {
```

How do I want to receive data according to the variable abc ?
abc's value is number .

Comment: What SQL library are you using?

Comment: @MCH use sqlite3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var abc = 1;
var query = 'select CollectionID, CollectionName from Collection where CollectionID = ?'
db.all (query, [abc], function (err, rows) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(rows);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the results I wanted.